# Split a string while ignoring the char of the delimiter?

Tags: c#

I am doing the split of the following string using the delimiter ' **/** '
The problem is that in the same string I have a ' **-** ' character that would like to remove it and what I have there after.

Input

```
var test = "This/ is /a - test";
 test.Split('/');
```

Output

```
test[0] = "This"
test[1] = "is"
test[2] = "a - test"
```

In test [2] it should be "a"

Comment: why would it, why does it not keep the spaces and the " - test" portion?

Comment: The information will not be relevant to me at the moment

Comment: What about `This/ is /a - test/ and - another/ test` ?

Comment: so if there is a `-` you want to split it too? Or just remove everything from the `-` to end?

Comment: @EpicKip, just remove

Comment: Need an answer to the @Lasse question, and some more context to the big picture to give a correct answer.

Comment: You could also just use the overload that accepts an array to split with. `"This/ is /a - test".Split(new[] { '/', '-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim())` output: `string[] { "This", "is", "a", "test" }`  It won't be index 2 anymore but that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the string on the `-` character.  You said you wish to ignore everything after that so take the `[0]` index of the resulting array and perform your second string split on the that, splitting on: `/`

```
var test = "This/ is /a - test";
string[] hyphenSplit = test.Split('-');
string[] slashSplit = hyphenSplit[0].Split('/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this work for you?

```
var test = "This/ is /a - test";
var split1 = test.Split('-');
var split2 = split1[0].Split('/');
```

Basically what maccettura said.

Comment: Yes, I can use that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Regex solution based on an explicit capture of one group:

```
String myText = "This/ is /a normal - test/ and quite - another/ test";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"[/]?\s*(?<part>[^-/]+[^-/\s])[^/]*[/]?", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

var strings = regex.Matches(myText).Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups["part"].Value);

Console.WriteLine(strings.Aggregate((str1, str2) => str1 + ">" + str2));
```

This will yield:

`This>is>a normal>and quite>test`

Answer (score -1):

again split it for '-'

```
test[2] = test[2].Split('-')[0];
```